# Eclipse white box behind cursor

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor

I know it might not seem like a serious question but for about a year that I'm using
Eclipse(Juno) I was not able able to understand why sometimes a white box appears (usually behind
my cursor in whitespace). I can't seem to be able to make it go away! Below is what it looks like:

[image: White box in Eclipse]

Does anyone know how can I get rid of this white box(if it is possible at all) and why
it appears in the first place?

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Is it a space between tab characters?

Comment: I'm not really sure! It changes position when I move my cursor around the text

Comment: What operating system? Does this happen in only Java files or other file types, too?

Comment: It is Windows 8 x64 and so far I've only noticed it in java files. It might have something to do with the distance between an empty and closed curly brace but I can't seem to be able to trigger it voluntarily

Comment: Maybe you can try changing the theme: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin

Comment: I think asking such question on the eclipse forum is more convenient.

Comment: May it is just a bug in eclipse, did you try the newest version?